# Problem loading MORE than one custom font blackberry

Tags: blackberry, fonts, font-family

I tried to load a custom font, which works. Now I have got the problem Iam not able to use more than one custom font in an application. If i add three labelFields each with a different font, only the last custom font is used for all labels.

If i delete the last setFont for the last label the second font is used. Is there some kind of mechanism which uses only the last font?

Here is the code which add the LabelFields and sets the fonts

```
        LabelField TestLabel1 = new LabelField("Test Label 1");
    Font fo1 = loadCustomFonts("FirstFont.ttf", "FirstFont", 0, 30);

    TestLabel1.setFont(fo1);
    add(TestLabel1);

    LabelField TestLabel2 = new LabelField("Test Label 2");
    Font fo2 = loadCustomFonts("SecondFont.ttf", "SecondFont", 0, 30);
    TestLabel2.setFont(fo2);
    add(TestLabel2);

    LabelField TestLabel3 = new LabelField("Test Label 3");
    Font fo3 =loadCustomFonts("ThirdFont.TTF", "ThirdFont", 0, 30);
    TestLabel3.setFont(fo3);
    add(TestLabel3);
```

Here is my "loadCustomFonts" Method, which loads the custom Font and returns a font object.

```
 public Font loadCustomFonts (String path, String fontname,int fontStyle, int fontSize){ 
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
    if (FontManager.getInstance().load(stream, fontname, FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.SUCCESS){
        try{
            FontFamily family;
            add(new LabelField("A"));
            family = FontFamily.forName(fontname);
            Font myFont = family.getFont(fontStyle,fontSize);
            return myFont;
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
    }
    else {
         try{
             FontFamily family;
             add(new LabelField("B"));
             family = FontFamily.forName(fontname);
             Font myFont = family.getFont(fontStyle,fontSize);
             return myFont;
         } 
         catch (ClassNotFoundException e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the reason. It was the maximum size of 60kb per custom font and if the font was allready loaded.

So I changed the loader method.

```
public Font loadCustomFonts (String path, String fontname,int fontStyle, int fontSize){
    //Loads custom Fonts        

        InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
        System.out.println("fontname"+fontname);

        //System.out.println("fontname"+fontname +"FontManager Return "+FontManager.getInstance().load(path, fontname, FontManager.EXCEEDS_LIMIT));
        if (FontManager.getInstance().load(stream, fontname, FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.EXCEEDS_LIMIT)
            System.out.println("FontManager.EXCEEDS_LIMIT => true");
        else
            System.out.println("FontManager.EXCEEDS_LIMIT => false");               

        System.out.println (FontManager.DUPLICATE_DATA);

         if (FontManager.getInstance().load(path, fontname, FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) 
         { 
        //if (FontManager.getInstance().load(stream, fontname, FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.SUCCESS){
            System.out.println("A getInstanc => true");
            try{
                System.out.println("A Try");
                FontFamily family;       
                family = FontFamily.forName(fontname);
                Font myFont = family.getFont(fontStyle,fontSize);
                System.out.println("A  return myFont"+myFont);
                return myFont;
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
                System.out.println("A Catch");
        }
        else {
        //font could not be loaded   
             System.out.println("B getInstanc => false");
             System.out.println("FontManager.getInstance().load(path, fontname, FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT"+FontManager.getInstance().load(path, fontname, FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT));
             if (FontManager.getInstance().load(path, fontname, FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.DUPLICATE_NAME)
            //check if font already is loaded
                 try{
                        System.out.println("B Try");
                        FontFamily family;       
                        family = FontFamily.forName(fontname);
                        Font myFont = family.getFont(fontStyle,fontSize);
                        System.out.println("B  return myFont"+myFont);
                        return myFont;
                    } 
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}               
            else
                 System.out.println("FontManager.getInstance().load(path, fontname, FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT"+FontManager.getInstance().load(path, fontname, FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT));

         }
        return null;
    }
```

Does someone know a solution to load fonts which are bigger than 60kb ? I already tried to use a input stream but it did not work.

(the limit "FontManager.EXCEEDS_LIMIT if font data exceeds 60k in size. " - http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FontManager.html#load%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: You would be better off asking your follow up question as a seperate question.

Answer (score 1):

try to override the paint() of the each labelfield and apply setFont inside it.

Comment: I tried to override it with the following but it doesn't work
'LabelField testLabel2 = new LabelField("Test Label 2"){
         public void paint (Graphics graphics){
           Font fo2 = loadCustomFonts("SmartCourierEUR-ExtraBoldCn.ttf", "SmartCourierEUR-ExtraBoldCn", 0, 30);
           System.out.println("font 2:"+fo2);
           this.setFont(fo2);
         }
        };
        add(testLabel2);'

Comment: add super.paint(graphics); after setfont

Answer (score 0):

```
       LabelField lf1 = new LabelField("This is font 1"){

        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
        {
            setFont( getFont().derive(Font.STYLE_BOLD,15));
            graphics.drawText(getText(), 1, 1);
            super.paint(graphics);

        }
    };

    LabelField lf2 = new LabelField("This is font 2"){

        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
        {
            setFont( getFont().derive(Font.STYLE_ITALIC,18));
            graphics.drawText(getText(), 1, 1);
            super.paint(graphics);

        }
    };
    LabelField lf3 = new LabelField("This is font 3"){

        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
        {
            setFont( getFont().derive(Font.STYLE_UNDERLINED,20));
            graphics.drawText(getText(), 1, 1);
            super.paint(graphics);

        }
    };

    add(lf1);
    add(lf2);
    add(lf3);
```

Comment: could you explain where I can load my custom fonts in this code?

Comment: @Martin you can add your customfont like this: setFont( loadCustomFonts("SecondFont.ttf", "SecondFont", 0, 30) );